# Domain + subdomain IIS deployment

Tags: asp.net, .net, go, iis, windows-server

I have two web-sites. First is asp.net core web ui. Second is golang api. Also I have bought domain. foo.bar (for example). I need two web-sites:

1. foo.bar - asp.net ui
2. api.foo.bar - go api

How can I deploy that on iis?
My go-server works on port 8080. I tried create two sites:

1. with blank hostname
2. hostname: api.foo.bar

And foo.bar (ui) works

Also I tried redirect api-traffic to port 8080 with iis rule but it doesn't work. For api.foo.bar I just get error 404.
The only thing I get is that api.foo.bar:8080 opens correctly on from server's browser.

Comment: In IIS when you create a site you need to fill in the host header box.  This would have your subdomain api.xxx.com and for the other you can use xxx.com for the UI.  There are a number of tutorials in setting up subdomains on IIS google will help.

Comment: I have no problems with routing. Problem is that http redirection doesn't redirect url to localhost:8080

Comment: In no case you should ever redirect any request. Learn about HttpPlatfomHandler and use it to host your Go web app, https://halfblood.pro/the-rough-history-of-iis-httpplatformhandler/

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly, do you mean you want to host 2 domains under one site? if so, you can achieve this by url rewrite, for more information you can refer to this link: [https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-url-rewrite-hosting-multiple-domains-under-one-site](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-url-rewrite-hosting-multiple-domains-under-one-site).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created two sites:

1. foo.bar (for asp.net ui) with blank hostname;
2. hostname: api.foo.bar for api.

Then I put rewrite-rule in web.config for api-site:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
      <remove name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" />
      <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8080/{R:0}" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

And everything worked